# Deleting suffix from feature class name using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, feature-class, delete

I have to edit the Name of the feature classes in my databank by deleting the Suffix part called "_AAA_VV". I am not pro in ArcPy but prepared something which does not work.

Can you help to find my mistake?

```
import arcpy, os
database = r'C:...\Data_test.gdb' 

try:
for dataset in datasets:
    arcpy.env.workspace = os.path.join(database,dataset)
    features = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
    for feature in features:
     #  feature.replace('_AAA_VV,'')
        feature.split('_AAA_VV,1)[0]

except Exception as e:
print("Found an error - {0}".format(e))
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work

```
import arcpy

database = r'C:...\Data_test.gdb'
arcpy.env.workspace = database
datalist = arcpy.ListDatasets("*", "Feature")

for data in datalist:
    try:
        features = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*", "ALL", data)
        for feature in features:
            split = feature.split('_AAA_VV')
            arcpy.Rename_management(feature, split[0])
    except IndexError:
        print('Error found in feature - {0}'.format(feature))
```